# How to configure a message channel between 2 brokers in RocketMQ

Tags: java, rocketmq

We used ActiveMQ to configure network connector to implement a message channel between 2 brokers, now we want to used RocketMQ. But I read many articles, there seems to be no concept about 'Channel' like WebSphere MQ or 'Network Connector' like ActiveMQ in RocketMQ. So how to configure a message channel between 2 brokers in RockemtMQ? Or how to implement the scenario of 'channel' like WMQ or AMQ in RocketMQ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to , slave will automatically update the master address from name server.

You only need to do:

1. They both register to the same name server address.
2. Your master and slave have the same broker name and cluster name, so that name server knows they are in the same group.

But if you indeed need to setup it manually, just config `haMasterAddress` in your slave configuration file:

```
haMasterAddress=YOUR_MASTER_ADDRESS_HERE
```

That will stop slave updating master addresses from name server